# ToolStripButton.Left property is missing

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstripbutton

I need to set a panel.Left property equal to a ToolStripButton.Left value:

```
pan1.Left = btn1.Left;
```

but there is no such property for ToolStripButton.
Is there a solution, please.

If there is no - how to place the panel on the center of a Form.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any kind of `control` to infer center, but form itself:

```
panel1.Left = this.ClientSize.Width / 2 - panel1.Width / 2;
```

Comment: Thank You, it works. But, I'm wondering that a button has not .Left value.

Comment: If you know index `N` of ToolStripButton then you can calculate it's `Left` by such formula `toolStrip1.Left + 10 /*some padding*/ + N * toolStrip1.Items[0].Width`

Answer (score 1):

this works:

```
pan1.Location = new Point(btn1.Bounds.X,pan1.Location.Y);
```

Comment: nice :-) Don't forget to add `toolStrip1.Left` to `Bounds.X` if toolStrip is not docked.